# Printing loop controller iteration number in beanshell scripting

Tags: jmeter

I have a scenario.
ThreadGroup `(loop value set to 1)`,
loop controller `(value set to 5)`,
 HTTP request,
 Beanshell preprocessor

In Beanshell preprocessor i need to print loop controller iteration value like 1,2,3,4,5.
I use `log.info(vars.getIteration());` but it prints `(Threadgroup loop iteration number)`

Will anybody guide me how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you're trying to achieve:

- Either use [Counter](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Counter) configuration element and print the "Reference Name" variable via `vars.get("foo");`
- or put [__counter()](https://docs.blazemeter.com/customer/portal/articles/1743668-using-jmeter-functions---part-ii) function somewhere, i.e. in "Parameters" input like `${__counter(,)}` and refer it as `log.info("Current iteration: " + Parameters);`
- or define a variable and increment it as required like:

  ```
  int iteration = vars.getObject("iteration"));
  iteration++;
  vars.putObject("iteration", iteration);
  ```